# Convert and parse digitally created PDF file to tesseract tsv file directly from PDF source code

Tags: csv, parsing, pdf, tesseract

I am trying to convert and parse a digitally created PDF file to tesseract tsv file. And to use this as ground truth for testing tesseract OCR performance on my PDF to TIF to TSV pipeline.

Any idea how I can achieve this task --- convert and parse a digitally created PDF file to a tesseract tsv file, without OCR or anything?

So far, I can use packages such as fitz PyMuPDF, pdfminer to extract texts. Using fitz PyMuPDF can give me sentences with their box location the PDF file (x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2). However, I don't see anyway yet to parse to tesseract-like tsv outputs. See https://blog.tomrochette.com/tesseract-tsv-format.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)